# MySQL JSON Query sends random numbers

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json, pymysql

I'm writing a MySQL Query in Python using pymysql to send JSON data to a MySQL table. When it sends the data, the following results are produced.

```
| id | data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 21 | 0x7B226775696C6473223A207B22383538393137313431303633343031353132223A207B226D656D62657273223A207B22343130373936333038323431303535373436223A207B22706F696E7473223A203137302C2022726166666C65735F776F6E223A20307D7D2C2022726166666C6573223A20307D7D7D |
```

The code I used to send the data is the following:

```
        self.data_str = json.dumps(self.data)
        sql = "insert into jsondata ( data) values ('" + self.data_str + "') "
        mysql.exec_sql(sql)
        mysql.close_db()
```

The exec_sql function is:

```
    def exec_sql(self, sql):
        # sql is insert, delete or update statement
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            # commit sql to mysql
            self.db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            return True
        except:
            self.db.rollback()
        return False
```

An example line of JSON data is

```
{"guilds": {"853317141063401512": {"members": {"410846308241055746": {"points": 250, "raffles_won": 0}}, "raffles": 0}}}
```

My SQL table was setup as follows:

```
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data  | blob   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What do you think `blob` type means? If you know that it means binary data, why are you storing a string there?

Comment: Oh haha, I cant believe I completely overlooked that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes are not random. They are the hex representation of ASCII bytes in your JSON string. Observe:

```
mysql> select unhex('7B226775696C6473223A207B22383538393137313431303633343031353132223A207B226D656D62657273223A207B22343130373936333038323431303535373436223A207B22706F696E7473223A203137302C2022726166666C65735F776F6E223A20307D7D2C2022726166666C6573223A20307D7D7D') as j;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| j                                                                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"guilds": {"858917141063401512": {"members": {"410796308241055746": {"points": 170, "raffles_won": 0}}, "raffles": 0}}} |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What you're seeing is that when you store a JSON string in a binary column (BLOB), MySQL "forgets" that it is supposed to be text, and dumps only the hex encoding of the bytes when you query it.

If you want to store JSON, then use [the JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), not BLOB.